# Grading Software Keeps Flagging Answer - Integers Between Min and Max of Data in R

Tags: integer, sequence, edx, minmax

Good day, the following is the problem I am trying to answer.

"Which integer values are between the maximum and minimum heights? For example, if the minimum height is 10.2 and the maximum height is 20.8, your answer should be x <- 11:20 to capture the integers in between those values. (If either the maximum or minimum height are integers, include those values too.)

Write code to create a vector x that includes the integers between the minimum and maximum heights (as numbers).
There are multiple ways to solve this problem, but the grader expects you to use the format in the problem description. Your answer should have numbers and a colon (:), and it should not use other functions."

My Answer: Given that the min and max of the data are 50 and 82.7 respectively, the answer should be 50:82 (I have also tried 50:83).

Help: Both answers are being flagged as incorrect. Am I doing something wrong here?

Further Info: This is an assignment from an EdX Course. I am using the "heights" data set from the "dslabs" library.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking this class as well.  And I was confused by the format they wanted the answer in.  This is what they are looking for:

x <- 50:82

Answer (score 0):

Write code to create a vector x that includes the integers between the minimum and maximum heights.

x <- 50:82
How many of the integers in x are NOT heights in the dataset?

sum(!(x %in% heights$height))

### [1] 3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).